# How to divide two columns in SQL?

Tags: sql

How can you divide two different columns in SQL?

I tried doing this:

```
SELECT population, surfaceArea 
FROM dbo.country
WHERE population / surfaceArea
```

But this does not work, how could you do this?

Comment: why are you doing the division in the where statement?

Comment: Please, when you're asking for help, **what does "doesn't work" mean?** What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message? If you did get an error, paste the entire message instead of paraphrasing. Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressions that you want to return go in the `SELECT` clause.  You might also want to check for divide-by-zero.  That suggests:

```
SELECT population, surfaceArea, population / nullif(surfaceArea, 0)
FROM dbo.country;
```